# Subquerying Using LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm developing a case management system in ASP.net MVC 5, using Entity Framework to manage the data interaction.

I have two tables *SupportCase* and *Interaction*. (These are connected by the person who is in charge of the case. PersonID)

In a razor view I list all of the SupportCases relevant to that user, but I also want to display the Last Interaction Date for that case.  (i.e SELECT TOP(1) InteractionDate FROM Interaction WHERE.... ORDER BY InteractionDate Desc)

I've tried creating a View in SQL Server for the SupportCase table which calculates various stats on the case including LastInteractionDate.  I'm having trouble getting Entity Framework to join the *SupportCase* table to the *Stats* view though.

I've also tried joining the two in LINQ, but with little success.

What is the most natural way to get the desired result?  I'm predominantly a SQL Developer, so a solution where I can join a view to a table in EF would be ideal, but I keep getting EF Error 3027.

Is this trivially easy in LINQ, and I am just missing a trick?

Many thanks

Comment: Show us some code ...

Comment: Ef or Ef core? If Ef what version? Ef code first ? model first ? database first ?

Comment: Do you have a little 2 bogus table where you can reproduce the issue to share?

Comment: When I see 3027, I think about regenerate the database from the model.

Comment: EF 6.2 - I will add some code if required, but not sure what would be relevant.  I could add my attempt at joining them in LINQ?

Comment: please show some code that you have tried.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly typical use case, but you need to make the jump to the OO paradigm. There are generally no needs for JOINS or even database views unless you are doing something out of the norm. For example, your design might have a `SupportCase` object with a navigation property that is a collection of `Interactions`. Now you can perform various LINQ operations.